# Repeated fingerprinting after array updates

Tags: algorithms, information-theory, hash, rolling-hash

I've got a microprocessor and want to quickly identify the settings of my application (stored in some eeprom regions) via a fingerprint instead of having to dump the entire memory every time.

So I was going to compute a **32-bit hash from the few kbytes**, but I am not sure which algorithm to use. It doesn't need to be cryptographically secure, but it should be fast and not need some large lookup tables. And most importantly, **whenever one of the settings (bytes) changes I need to recompute the hash**, which I want to do efficiently.

I guessed I could use any regular hashing algorithm and modify it so that it stores intermediate results in a tree-like structure which trades some memory for a logarithmic benefit in recomputation complexity. (As I found in my research, this concept seems to be called [merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree)). But surely there's an even better way to do it.

I then found about [rolling hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) which employ some recursive algorithms, generalised to

$H(arr) = f_r(\ldots f_r(f_r(f_r(f_0 \oplus arr_0) \oplus arr_1) \oplus arr_2) \ldots \oplus arr_n)$

that can be expanded to

$H(arr) = f_0 \oplus f^0(arr_0) \oplus f^1(arr_1) \oplus f^2(arr_2) \oplus \ldots \oplus f^n(arr_n)$

This appears perfect for my use case if $\oplus$ is associative, commutative and reversible, which allows to do the recomputation for updating the array at index $i$ by

$H(arr_{new}) = H(arr_{old}) \ominus f^i(arr_{old,i}) \oplus f^i(arr_{new,i})$

The natural choices for $\oplus$ are bitwise XOR and modular addition, but **which hash algorithms employ them, use a both simple and fast $f^i$ implementation, and still have good hashing characteristics?**

---

I found some but am not totally satisfied.

- [CRC32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) is known to be fast, and although all descriptions of the algorithm are iterative, I'm confident to be able to derive a non-recursive $f$ function (knowing that crcs have the property $\operatorname{crc}(x \oplus y \oplus z) = \operatorname{crc}(x) \oplus \operatorname{crc}(y) \oplus \operatorname{crc}(z)$). Still, CRC is used and designed for error detection, not fingerprinting, so maybe it's not suitable at all. Am I missing something there?
- [Rabin fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint) appears to be suited better, but I only found iterative implementations with explicit polynom division. Not sure how to derive $f^i$ for this (is it even possible?). Also I'm not certain how it does differ from CRC computation.
- [Rabin-Karp rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Rabin-Karp_rolling_hash) appears to be a good choice, but I have concerns. Does "modulo $n$" imply I won't get all 32 bit values? Isn't the exponentiation $f^i(x) = x \cdot a^i$ relatively slow? And what constants $a$/$n$ should I use?
- [Cyclic polynomial / Buzhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Cyclic_polynomial) looks easy and efficiently to implement at first. But what about the $h$ in $f^i(x) = rotate(h(x), i)$, wouldn't this need to be a function that generates a 32-bit value from my 8-bit bytes? (I read a lookup table with random data works fine, but 256*4 bytes is too large for me). And isn't this rotation susceptible for swapping two settings that happen to be 32 bytes apart? Could the upper bytes of $i$, which is effectively used modulo 32, be utilised for something?

Can you dispel my doubts about any of these? Or is there some other algorithm that I missed entirely?

Comment: [This question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40986/which-fingerprinting-hashing-algorithms-support-compounding) seems related, but couldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Any of the first three options you list are likely to be fine for what you want.

The CRC provides a good fingerprint (indeed, there's some theory to back that up, based on the theory of Carter-Wegman hashing, 2-universal hashes, etc.).

The Rabin fingerprint is also fine, and is essentially equivalent to the CRC (modulo small technical details that are unimportant).  $f^i(m_i) = m_i x^i \bmod p(x)$, which can be readily computed even for very large values of $i$ using [fast modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

The Rabin-Karp hash is also fine, as long as you choose a good modulus $m$.  Don't pick a power of two; use a prime number.  Exponentiation is again fast if you use standard algorithms for fast modular exponentiation.  If possible, use a constant $a$ that is larger than the largest possible value of any single array element (single byte), i.e., larger than 256.  (Alternatively, it might be possible to pick $m$ to be a power of two if you also choose the constant $a$ to be a large random number modulo $m$; I haven't thought about that too carefully, so if that sounds attractive, please post a  separate question asking about that specific scenario.)

Buzhash is a little weaker than the other hash functions, though I suppose it's possible it might be good enough in practice.  Yes, Buzhash is susceptible to swapping of two values that are a multiple of 32 positions apart.  There might be ways to fix this, but given the large lookup tables required, that seems moot.  As you say, Buzhash requires a lookup table that maps from 8-bit values to 32-bit values (i.e., 256 entries, where each entry is a 32-bit word), so it sounds like Buzhash is not going to be feasible in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! I thought about fast exponentiation, I meant "relatively" slow when compared to the `rotate` of Buzhash. Regarding the modulus in Rabin-Karp, [$2^{31}-1$ seems popular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use).