# Efficiently extendable hash function?

Tags: strings, hash

I'm wondering whether there exist any good hash functions with the following property: Assume that $x$ is some string over some alphabet $A$, then given $H(x)$ we can compute in $O(1)$ time both $H(ax)$ and $H(xa)$ for any letter $a\in A$. In practice one can assume that $A$ is for example the set of $8$-bit integers.

In other words, a hash function for strings that can quickly be extended in both directions. I'm only interested in hash functions that actually distribute the data well and which are very fast to compute in practice.

Comment: If you track the length of the input, the [Java `String.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) function has this property. While it is indeed _very fast to compute in practice_, it is rather more debatable whether it _distributes the data well_.

Comment: @Littlish I think your edit actually changed the meaning of the first sentence here. The question wasn't whether there exists a _well-known_ hash function with this property, but whether existed a _known_ hash function with this property that is also _good_, i.e. has desirable distribution properties such as avalanche effect.

Answer (score 2):

Use any rolling hash, e.g., the [Rabin-karp rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Rabin-Karp_rolling_hash), [Buzhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Cyclic_polynomial), or CRC.  See also the following resources:

- [additive hash function](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/102731/755)
- [Can ropes (AVL trees) be interned?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/90966/755)
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/17935/351
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11420/351
- the answers to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1558/351